# Consecutive number the input numbers can be in any order

Tags: java

I need to test for consecutive numbers in any order. My program seems to work ok when I type in numbers in order like `1,2,3` or `8,3,3`, but I need this to read the numbers in any order, for example `3,2,4` should return true.

Examples that should return `true`:

- `(1,2,3)`
- `(3,2,4)`
- `(-10,-8,-9)`

Examples that should return `false`:

- `(3,5,7)`
- `(1,2,2)`
- `(7,7,9)`

.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Consecutive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter three numbers");
        String numbers = console.nextLine();

        System.out.println("The numbers (" + numbers + ") is '" + consecutive(numbers) + "'");
    }

    private static boolean consecutive(String str) {
        char c = str.charAt(0);
        for (int cc = 1; cc < str.length(); cc++)
            if ((c + 1) != str.charAt(cc))
                return false;
            else
                c++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by consecutive? Ordered so that each following number is larger? Ordered so each is smaller?

Comment: You need to sort the string first, as an integer array, in your consecutive method, then proceed.

Comment: Sort a String? Or do you mean to sort a list of characters...

Comment: @mbroshi Sorting the numbers in the string would defeat the purpose of checking if the numbers are consecutive.

Comment: @TerryChern Maybe I misunderstood, but he said he wanted 3, 2, 4 to return true.

Comment: @TerryChern Not really. It's much easier to tell if integers are consecutive if they are in order.

Comment: @Stendika Oh, I see what he meant now, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @mbroshi Yes, I see that now, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: for exameple when i type in 1,2,3  or 3,2,4  or -10,-8-9  i should get a true return! cus they are all consecutive number even when they are not in order !

Comment: Are you required to parse in the numbers with commas? Or is it a single input?

Comment: Yes with commas !! i just relize that i did't use commas sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Based on a few assumptions (you want them in any order, they will always be comma-delimited), you will need to check for consecutivity on a sorted array with some like the follows:

```
    String[] split = str.split(",");
    int[] numbers = new int[split.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    (...now check for consecutivity...)
```

Comment: lol, I should have updated the post to see if someone had written this already; ended up typing the whole thing up and then posting only to find that you'd already implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Consecutive {

private ArrayList<Integer> numberList;

public Consecutive() {
    numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    fetchInput();

    sortNumberList();

    System.out.println(isConsecutive());
}

private void fetchInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter any amount of numbers"
            + " separated by space.\n" + "Exit by typing any letter and"
            + " pressing Enter key.");

    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        numberList.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    scanner.close();
}

// Sort the list in ascending order
private void sortNumberList() {
    Collections.sort(numberList);
}

private boolean isConsecutive() {
    // Loop through the sorted number list
    for (int index = 0, length = numberList.size() - 1; index < length; index++) {
        // Check if the two adjacent numbers are differing by the value 1 or
        // not.
        if (numberList.get(index + 1) - numberList.get(index) != 1)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Consecutive();
}
}
```

First fetch the input, and store the input in an Array. Sort the array, and then check if the sorted array has any adjacent elements which don't differ by the value of 1.
If there is any such adjacent pair, then that means that the elements that were entered weren't consecutive.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is way to advance for me lol... but thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the sort method suggested by stendika; first convert to an array, removing all the commas, then sort and compare elements.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Consecutive{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter three numbers");
        String numbers = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println( "The numbers (" + numbers + ") is '" + consecutive( numbers ) + "'" );
    }//end of main


    private static boolean consecutive(String str) {
        String[] numbers = str.split(",");
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length-1; index++){
            if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]) > Integer.parseInt(numbers[index+1])){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }//end of consecutive method
}
```